# Adding a border to the top of a uitabbaritem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I would like to highlight a selected `UITabBarItem` by adding a 2 point border with colour to the top of it. I thought it would be a simple case of looping using add sub view but you can't gain access to the view of the `UITabBarItem`. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you instead using of icon image? if you go with icon image then use following this code. 

[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NormalImage"] 
withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BorderImage"]];

Comment: You can use two different image for tab bar for selected state and normal state  like https://stackoverflow.com/a/26802597/4601900

Comment: I think you need this https://stackoverflow.com/q/32668812/4601900

Comment: This answer looks like it could do the job for you. It's using Swift, but easy to convert to Obj-C. And, it's drawing the line on the bottom, but again, easy to convert to the top: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33670450/6257435